# Scala - Deleting spaces

Tags: scala

I have a string that looks like this

```
svchost.exe                   4464 Services                   0        47.656 K
```

*note that there are many spaces and the amount of spaces are different in each case*

I want to extract the name `svchost.exe` and the pid `4464`. I would be able to do this, but only with the imperative way. Its hard for me to think in a functional way to solve this problem.

It is possible to solve this with regex but I want to see how you do something like this with functional programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy peasy:

```
val s = "svchost.exe                   4464 Services                   0        47.656 K"
s.split(" ").filterNot(str => str == "")
// Array[java.lang.String] = Array(svchost.exe, 4464, Services, 0, 47.656, K)
```

**UPDATE**

or use `s.split(" +")` which relies on regexp beauty

Comment: I would `s.split(' ').filter(_.length > 0)`, but same deal.  Well, assuming that `s.split(" +")` is forbidden by the premise of the question.

Comment: I'd replace " " with @Tomasz " +" version.

Answer (score 10):

Exploit the fact that [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) accepts a regular expression:

```
s.split(" +")  //Array(svchost.exe, 4464, Services, 0, 47.656, K)
```

No post-filtering required.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't actually a good way to do it, but:

```
(s,s.drop(1)+" ").zipped.filter(_!=' ' || _!=' ')._1.split(' ')
```

would be an approach to use if it wasn't a string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this answers your question; it may not, since it uses a regular expression, but then again, so do some of the other answers, and this at least uses pattern matching.

Use a regular expression:

```
val str = "svchost.exe                   4464 Services                   0        47.656 K"
val Process = """^([^\s]*)[\s]*([^\s]*).*$""".r
val Process(name, pid) = str
```

Enter this in the REPL, and you get:

```
name: String = svchost.exe
pid: String = 4464
```

By using `\s`, you also cover for other types of whitespace, which may be relevant in the above case. (Tab characters?)